# Unable to install `pg` gem on CentOS 7 VM

Tags: ruby, postgresql, centos, ld, pg

I'm unable to install the `pg` gem on an AWS EC2 server running CentOS 7. I'm reasonably confident there are no issues with my Ruby install (2.7.0), gemset, RVM, etc.. and am receiving the error message below. I have installed `postgresql`, `postgresql-devel`, `postgresql-libs`, and `postgresql-server` as suggested in similar questions on here. Postgres is 9.2.24 which should be compatible with the `pg` gem.

I have also tried specifying the `pg_conf` file and installing with the command `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config` and received the same error.

I've encountered issues in the past attempting to install `pg` on Mac and other Linux systems, but this error is new to me. I'm hitting my head against the wall.

```sh
current directory: /home/MY_USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@GEMSET_NAME/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/home/MY_USERNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby -I /home/MY_USERNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200714-11146-p34b9c.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... no
checking for PQsslAttribute()... no
checking for PQresultVerboseErrorMessage()... no
checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... no
checking for PQresultMemorySize()... no
checking for timegm()... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage()... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/MY_USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@GEMSET_NAME/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/MY_USERNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@GEMSET_NAME/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
compiling pg_connection.c
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_record_coder.c
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
compiling pg_tuple.c
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
compiling pg_util.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.so
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--compress-debug-sections=zlib'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: I doubt if anyone will be willing to dig into a problem with ancient software like PostgreSQL 9.2. You should try with recent versions of everything.

Comment: The error message seems to be with `ld` not recognizing an option. This is part of the C toolchain, not necessarily related to Ruby or the pg gem. I can think of two general approaches: look through the gem's build directory to find where that argument is being passed to ld and try to prevent it, or try to replace your system's version of ld with one that would recognize the option.

Comment: Thank you @Max! The problem was with `ld`, and upgrading solved the problem. For anyone in a similar situation, I did a full `sudo yum upgrade` which upgraded GNU's `binutils` (of which `ld` is a part) and now I can install `pg` without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from [Max's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902479/unable-to-install-pg-gem-on-centos-7-vm#comment111259202_62902479).

The issue was with `ld`, not postgres. My `ld` version (`ld -v` was antiquated and I did a full system upgrade (`sudo yum upgrade`) which upgraded GNU's `binutils` (of which `ld` is a part) and now I can install `pg` without issue.

Answer (score 1):

This link [here](https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/postgresql-centos7-directadmin/) contained commands that worked for me.  Specifically these lines -->

```
[ -f `/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_config --includedir`/libpq-fe.h ] && echo "devel installed" || echo "devel missing"
# scl-rh for llvm-toolset-7-clang 4.0.1
yum -y install centos-release-scl-rh 
yum-config-manager --disable centos-sclo-rh
yum -y install postgresql12-devel --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh
```